# Redstone torch not working in Minecraft beta 1.1_02?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Torches seem to be stuck ON all the time.  Given

`SrrTrr`  (Switch, redstone, Torch)

the torch and all the redstone are lit regardless of the position of the switch.  Removing the torch shows the switch and redstone connected to it function as expected.  Is anyone else seeing this?

FWIW, this is running on a local server (same version) with default options and no plugins.  I believe the server was running the first beta version when the world was created.

I've read/watched a number of tutorials and it doesn't appear I'm doing anything wrong.  Can anyone running on bete 1.1_02 server/client combination confirm this?

Comment: All the redstone including those _before_ the torch?

Comment: Is this behavior new in the beta?  I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

A redstone torch on the ground will light things up.  What you need is:

```
   T   
SrrBTr
```

Where the second torch is on the side of the block.  This will make a not gate. The tiles next to the block are input, while the tiles next to the leaning torch are outputs.

Comment: The torch on top is unnecessary.

Comment: You might be right.

Comment: He is right :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the torch to turn off, you do this (Where B = Block, D = Redstone Dust, T  = Redstone torch, and L = Lever):

```
LDDBTDD
```